# How to Connect Android bluetooth to send data

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am new to Android and I am trying to make an application to connect and send data via Bluetooth, can anybody help me start my application.

Comment: What help do you need? What have you tried so far, what books and articles have you read, what tutorials have you studied?

Comment: Hi, first of all I'd recommend looking through the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), it's got a few examples that will help you start using bluetooth in your applications. Are you having any particular problems? If so, post the code as it'll enable us to help you with specific problems!

Comment: Documentation is indeed very helpful, it's all I ever needed.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking to do but here are several examples:

http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-simple-spp.html

http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/arduino-to-android-basic-bluetooth.html

http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/arduino-to-android-turning-led-on-and.html

The first example shows how to setup an SPP client and server using an Android device and a Windows PC and send data from the Andriod device to the PC.  On Windows it has server examples in java and perl.

The second example shows how to setup basic bluetooth connectivity between an Android device and an Arduino.

The third example builds on the second example and shows how to send data from Android to the Arduino using a program.

The examples should have all the code for Android, Windows and the Arduino.

Hope this helps.